# redis replica manual configuration

Tags: redis, replication

I want to make redis slave node to master node without turning off replication.

What ever is searched till now, I didn't get any solution to promote slave node to master node without losing data.

Is there any redis command to promote slave node to master in replication without losing data?

Comment: Have you tried Sentinel?

Comment: yeh I tried sentinel wonderful, but just asking for any manual solution